# What's is the meaning of “there's a lot of it about“ and “You can't get the wood, you know“

Tags: phrase-meaning

Hello everyone i have a doubt about the meaning of a couple of  expressions

I found them after typing my password in my computer and I wrote it wrong, but in the screen the next message appears

**There's a lot of it about, you know.**

And after a second attempt wrong too

**You can't get the wood, you know.**

Could someone help me to understand those phrases and when use them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

These phrases (note 'phrases' not 'phases') are simply random quotes from old world war 2 era British radio comedies.  Presumably whoever programmed the software you're using was fond of said comedies and thought it would be amusing to randomly insert quotes from them.  This is clearly a stupid idea as it just causes confusion for the user, ie you.

OPINION STARTS: This is the sort of thing that happens when you let programmers design a system with insufficient managerial oversight. /OPINION ENDS

Since they're totally random, there's no guidance for using them, apart from "Don't bother, you'd just confuse people."

Comment: They are both catchphrases from The Goon Show - 1950s - 1960s.